# Technologies to use in a peer to peer, file sync, high availability, cluster like, backup solution

Tags: web-server, backup, vpn, cluster, file-server

I've been doing research on how to setup a self host backup high availability solution using raspberry pi's. The biggest requirement is master to master replication and cross platform client support. One thing that is a big focus is that the raspbery pi's might not be on the same lan network, maybe ever at a different house. Should be able to remove a hard drive and plug in a new one when there is a failure. Key thing to backup solutions is more than one copy. I want high availability and encryption.

After some research I've determined what may be the best opensourced solutions right now.

### Client syncing

- nextcloud - prefered option so far

  - has mobile and desktop sync clients
  - uses mysql or postgres db
- resilio

  - Seems to be easiest of any of the options, supports peer to peer on all devices, may be option 2 if database master to master replication on nextcloud doesn't work out. Only option of all the technologies that is not opensourced. Does not charge a subscription for consumers, pay once for family license.

### Server peer to peer file sync:

- [resilio](https://www.resilio.com/)

  - costs money if you use their client applications and want to do specific sub folders, doesn't cost for a full peer to peer replication, has a mobile client
- [dat](https://datproject.org/)

  - new peer to peer file protocol similar to websockets
- [syncthing](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing)

### Database master to master replication:

- biggest area of concern mainly for nextcloud file sharing service

#### Connection:

- how to connect and setup a cluster would be interesting

  - vpn
  - telebit
  - aws vpc vpn connection
  - some other protocol

#### Databases:

- mysql - supposedly supports clustering
- gundb - nosql db don't think it would work with nextcloud
- cockroach db - enterprise tested, has mysql and postgres api support
- yugabyte - postgres api supports clustering claims to be faster than cockroach db
- postgres - least likely to work has a master - slave replication support

### Access over internet:

- [telebit](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/telebit.js) - may support [load balancing](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/telebit.js/issues/29) with same configuration haven't tested
- openvpn - connect to vpn to access a raspberry pi hosted backup solution for a location

### Load balancing:

- pending research - several options out there, may have to be external from local network
- telebit suppposedly supports it
- could pay for aws application load balancer and connect local machines to aws vpc via aws vpn
- apache load balancer - doesn't guarantee health checks if one is down
- nginx load balancer

### Automated installation/startup - want to make as plug in and play as possible

- dietpi - works on rock64 and raspberry pi

  - has some already supported software and can setup an bash script to run on first install to install third party software
- startup service

  - besides starting up all other technologies put together, will send out an email with network information and a vpn cert to connect and debug a cluster instance having issues. Super easy using a bash script, just though I'd mention this.

### Honorable mentions:

- [syncloud](https://github.com/syncloud/platform) combines several of these technologies, but out of the box doesn't have [master to master](https://github.com/syncloud/platform/issues/389) replication recomendations.
- owncloud - nextcloud is a opensourced branch off of this
- backupbuddy - no ios solution
- syncthing - no ios solution, has a android solution

Are there alternative technologies that people here would recommend and why? Main concern seems to be the database master to master replication.